# get less than 30 days with max date values and check flag condition in sql server

Tags: sql-server, sql-server-2008-r2

Hi I have doubt about `Sql server`

```
table : Emp 


  Empid   | name |  Sdate        |  Flag | deptno | Deptname
    1     |test  | 2015-09-18    |   2   |10      |Hr 
    1     |tes   | 2014-09-13    |   2   |10      |ceo
    1     |hari  | 2015-09-14    |   2   |10      |Pm
    1     |balu  | 2015-09-05    |   5   |10      |cm
    1     |jai   | 2015-09-12    |   1   |20      |hr
    2     |kali  |2015-09-15     |   2   |20      |Deo
    2     |hni   |2015-09-04     |   5   |20      |br
    3     |jai   |2015-09-10     |   3   |20      |ceo
    3     |tes   |2015-09-20     |   3   |20      |hr
    3     |man   |2015-09-16     |   5   |20      |hal
    4     |op    |2015-09-12     |   2   |10      |har
    4     |jai   |2014-05-01     |   5   |10      |kal
```

based on above table I want output like below

Here change `Flag` values, but here actually changing names, because `deptname` remains from the row with value 2 >compare records based on `empid+ deptno`  and the `sdate`  of `flag=2` and `sdate` of
    `flag=5`, `sdate` should be less than or equal to `flag=2 sdate` and the difference
    between the `sdates` should be less than 30 days. we need apply  lesst than 30 days for flag 2 and 5 values only remain flag values(1,3) no  need to check date conditon.

```
  Empid     | name   | Sdate         | Flag   | deptno  | deptname
    1       | balu   | 2015-09-18    |   2    |10       |Hr
    1       |jai     | 2015-09-12    |   1    |20       |Hr
    2       |hni     |2015-09-15     |   2    |20       |Deo
    3       |jai     |2015-09-10     |   3    |20       |ceo
    3       |tes     |2015-09-20     |   3   |20        |hr
    3       |man     |2015-09-16     |   5    |20       |Hal
    4       |op      |2015-09-12     |   2    |10       |har
```

I Tried like below :

```
SELECT distinct a1.[id]
      ,isnull(a2.name,a1.name) as name,a1.flag,a1.deptno,a1.[sdate]
 FROM [testresult].[dbo].[emp1] as a1 left join [testresult].[dbo].[emp1] as a2 
  on a1.id=a2.id 
  and a1.deptno=a2.deptno
  and a1.[check] =2 and a2.[check]=5 and datediff(day,a2.sdate,a1.sdate)<=30
 where  
 not exists (select 1 from [testresult].[dbo].[emp1] as a3 where a3.id = a.id and  a3.deptno=a1.deptno
  and a1.flag = 5 and a3.flag = 2)
```

above query not give expected result .
please tell me how to write query to achive this task in sql server

Answer (score 0):

I'm not sure I correctly understand your query algorithm, but it seems to me that this query will meet your expectations.

```
DECLARE @emp1 Table  (EmpId INT, name NVARCHAR(10), Sdate DATE, Flag INT, deptno INT, deptname NVARCHAR(10))

INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (1, 'test', '20150918', 2, 10, 'Hr')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (1, 'tes', '20150913', 2, 10, 'ceo')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (1, 'hari', '20150914', 2, 10, 'Pm')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (1, 'balu', '20150905', 5, 10, 'cm')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (1, 'jai', '20150912', 1, 20, 'Hr')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (2, 'kali', '20150915', 2, 20, 'Deo')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (2, 'hni', '20150904', 5, 20, 'br')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (3, 'jai', '20150910', 3, 20, 'ceo')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (3, 'man', '20150916', 5, 20, 'hal')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (4, 'op', '20150915', 2, 10, 'har')
INSERT INTO @emp1 (EmpId, name, Sdate, Flag, deptno, deptname)
VALUES (4, 'jai', '20140501', 5, 10, 'kal')


    SELECT x.EmpId ,
   x.name ,
   x.Sdate ,
   x.Flag ,
   x.deptno ,
   x.deptname
   FROM
   (
      SELECT e.EmpId ,
         ISNULL(x.name,e.name) AS name ,
         e.Sdate ,
         e.Flag ,
         e.deptno ,
         e.deptname,
         ROW_NUMBER() OVER (PARTITION BY e.EmpId, e.deptno, e.Flag ORDER BY e.Sdate DESC) AS rn
      FROM
         @emp1 e
         LEFT JOIN 
         (  SELECT *
            FROM @emp1 e2 
            WHERE 
                EXISTS (SELECT * FROM @emp1 e4 WHERE e2.empid = e4.empid AND e2.deptno = e4.deptno AND e4.Flag = 2)
                AND ABS(ISNULL(DATEDIFF(DAY, (SELECT TOP 1 e1.Sdate FROM @emp1 e1 WHERE e2.EmpId = e1.EmpId AND e2.deptno = e1.deptno AND e1.Flag = 2), e2.Sdate),0)) < 30
        ) x
         ON e.EmpId = x.EmpId AND e.deptno = x.deptno AND x.Flag = 5
      WHERE
         (e.Flag <> 5 OR NOT EXISTS (SELECT 1 FROM @emp1 e3 WHERE e.EmpId = e3.EmpId AND e.deptno = e.deptno AND e3.Flag = 2))
    ) x
   WHERE 
       x.rn = 1
```

Comment: Thank you.In the output I want output 4 id correspond flag =2 value also when not less then 30 days of flag=5 values. can you please suggest/ provide query to me.

Comment: I corrected query. I hope that now this query meet your expectations.

Comment: Hi ,small correction for  check less than 30 days need only flag 2 and 5 only.can you please suggest / provide query to me. Thanks!